# Python - concatenating byte to string cutting off some bytes in string

Tags: python, byte, aes, pycrypto

I'm trying to decrypt an image file using Python with the AES cipher. We've been given a key with 15 bytes, and it's our job to decrypt the image running through the first byte.

and what I have so far is:

```
fifteenbytes = b'\x7e\x15\x16\x28\xae\xd2\xa6\xab\xf7\x15\x88\x09\xcf\x4f\x3c'

for i in range(0, 256):
    ipack = pack('B', i)

    key = ipack + fifteenbytes
```

I was hoping I'd be getting key as something like:

```
\x00\x7e\x15\x16\x28\xae\xd2\xa6\xab\xf7\x15\x88\x09\xcf\x4f\x3c
```

for iterations 0 - 255, but I end up with:

```
b'\x00~\x15\x16(\xae\xd2\xa6\xab\xf7\x15\x88\t\xcfO<'
```

or sometimes exit characters and ascii values like:

```
b'\t~\x15\x16(\xae\xd2\xa6\xab\xf7\x15\x88\t\xcfO<'
b'%~\x15\x16(\xae\xd2\xa6\xab\xf7\x15\x88\t\xcfO<'
```

Can someone please explain why this happens?

Comment: This is *normal*. Python bytes objects will be shown, where possible, with printable ASCII characters rather than using a `\xhh` escape sequence. *No data is lost here*, you are just looking at debugging output skewed towards readable text.

Comment: For example, the 7E byte is the `~` character in the ASCII standard, and as that's a printable character, the `repr()` output uses `~` rather than `\x7E`. This is helpful when your data is predominantly text as you then don't have to keep translating bytes to ASCII manually.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I see, thank you! So does that mean if I input a key to my cipher using 7E or ~, it would give me the same output?

Comment: Exactly; `b'~' == b'\x7e'`. The `\xhh` notation is just *syntax* to define a byte value, that can also be specified with `~`.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting correct output, but you appear to be confused by the `repr()` output for a `bytes` value.

Python gives you a value that can safely be copied and pasted back into a Python session. This aids debugging. This display uses ASCII printable text where possible to represent the value, but the value can be exactly reproduced with what is displayed.

Your expected value `b'\x00\x7e\x15\x16\x28\xae\xd2\xa6\xab\xf7\x15\x88\x09\xcf\x4f\x3c'` contains several ASCII characters that are printable, so Python shows those instead of the `\xhh` byte value:

```
>>> output = b'\x00\x7e\x15\x16\x28\xae\xd2\xa6\xab\xf7\x15\x88\x09\xcf\x4f\x3c'
>>> output 
b'\x00~\x15\x16(\xae\xd2\xa6\xab\xf7\x15\x88\t\xcfO<'
>>> output == b'\x00\x7e\x15\x16\x28\xae\xd2\xa6\xab\xf7\x15\x88\x09\xcf\x4f\x3c'
True
```

The bytestring is still 16 bytes long:

```
>>> len(output)
16
```

That `~` is ASCII codepoint 126, or 0x7E in hexadecimal:

```
>>> output[1]
126
>>> hex(output[1])
'0x7e'
```

The same applies to `\x28` and `(`, `\x09` and `\t` (the tab character escape sequence), `\x4f` and `O`, and `\x3c` and `<`.

The `\xhh` escape sequence is just notation in a `bytes` object literal to define a given byte value, but you can produce the exact same value with `~`. Ditto for `\t`, you can express that same value as `\x09`, but Python prefers using the `\t` sequence when showing the representation.